# Do there exist a theoretically exact DFT method and XC functional, possibly modified from those for closed-shell molecules, for open-shell molecules?

Tags: density-functional-theory, spin, exchange-correlation

I'm trying to analyse an extremely complex molecule's electron affinity; the molecule is much too large to perform post-HF methods on, meaning that open-shell DFT is the only option available. While I was searching in the literature for the functional that would be the most similar one, w.r.t the exact XC, for my molecule, I began to wonder if any modified versions of Kohn-Sham DFT and the exact XC functional could, at least theoretically, exactly describe the ground state densities of open-shell molecules, just like how they do for closed-shell molecules.

My question now follows- given an open-shell molecule, is there any such modification that is theoretically exact, i.e. ignoring "subtle" facts like how the exact closed-shell XC functional is unknown?

P.S. I'm asking the same question for both nonrelativistic and relativistic calculations.

P.S. 2: I'm not asking for the explicit exact functional- I'm asking whether such an exact potential theoretically exists at all.

Comment: What I know is that there is no any knowledge of the real mathematical form of the functional that allows to calculate the exchange-correlation term. We can estimate it just by parametrising it and so tanking into consideration several parameters (see Jacob ladder) to improve the quality of the estimation

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini I'm asking about the theoretical existence, not an explicit example.

Comment: I don't know this but I suspect that there should be an exact functional for open-shell as well as closed shell molecules. You just construct a density matrix for both alpha and beta densities, rather than treating them as equal as in the closed-shell case. Maybe I'm wrong, but I'd find it surprising.

Comment: There's nothing special about closed-shell atoms or molecules, the Hohenberg-Kohn theorem applies equally to open- and closed-shells, with the caveat that the original proof is not valid here and you should read Mel Levy's work to see a proof of the HK theorem for systems with degenerate ground states.